# How do I find the line number of a certain string in a text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Edit: Thanks for all the help guys! I already found my answer in the comments section but I don't know how to mark comments as answered! Thank you, Dainius Preimantas for answering my question!

I have a text file and would like to find a certain string in the text file and then return the number of the line in which the string is in?
For example:

```py
with open("File.txt", "r+") as f:
    f.find(stringvalue)
    linenumber = #whatever line number value is returned
```

Text file ("File.txt"):

> PasswordBank,jack789
>
> BankEpic,Epic1234
>
> Bank1,Bank123
>
> Master,Master123

Comment: Show us the text file, and show us your attempt in trying out the question on the said text file

Comment: You could try iterating trough all of the lines:                                                      
with open("file") as fp:
    for i, line in enumerate(fp):
     if string in line:
      ...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
f=open('filename.txt','r')
text=f.read().split('\n')
string_to_find='string'
for line in range(text):
    if string_to_find in text[line]:
        return line
```

in the future, when asking questions, refer to our guide on [how do i ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

```
substring = "42 is the answer"
filename = "file.txt"
with open(filename, "r") as file:
    line = file.readline()
    i = 1
    flag = False
    while line:
        if substring in line: #Or any other string matching condition
            flag = True
        if flag:
            break
        line = file.readline()
        i += 1
    if flag:
        print(i)
    else:
        print("Line not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

This works 100% I tried it for you

```
placeholder = 0

file = open("filename.txt", "r")
all_lines = file.readlines()

while placeholder < len(all_lines):
    each_line = all_lines[placeholder]
    if " yourString " in each_line:
        print("yes in line: " + str(placeholder+1))
        placeholder += 1
    else:
        placeholder += 1
```